# rails 4 update only nested attributes strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

I'm trying to update only the nested attributes when a certain submit button is clicked, but I can't figure out how to pass through only those params to the update action.

```
def update
  if params[:commit] == "Update Dogs"
    owner.update_attributes(params[dogs_attributes: [:id, :name, :tag]])
    render :show
  ...
  end
end

def owner_attributes
  params.fetch(:owner).permit(:id, :name, :address, dogs_attributes: [:id, :name, :tag])
end
```

It won't commit the changes. I've also tried

```
 owner.update_attributes(dogs_attributes)
```

but then I get the error "undefined method dogs_attributes". Tried defining it as its own method similar to owner_attributes but then ActionController couldn't fetch the param :dog. I've tried a whole bunch of variations on the above to no avail. It's probably a simple error but I can't figure out how to write this correctly. Any ideas?

PS. Owner does accept nested attributes for dogs.

Thanks!

Comment: `owner.update_attributes(owner_attributes)` ?

Comment: `owner.update_attributes(params[dogs_attributes: [:id, :name, :tag]])` what is it? ..it should be something like owner.update_attributes(owner_attributes)

Comment: but I only want to update the dogs attributes for the owner, there's some other stuff in the form I don't want changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why dont you specify a different set attributes just for the update method?

```
def update
    if params[:commit] == "Update Dogs"
        Owner.update_attributes(update_attr)
    else
        Owner.update_attributes(owner_attr)
    end
end

private
def update_attr
    params.require(:owner).permit(:dog_attributes[:id, :name, :tag])
end

def owner_attributes
  params.fetch(:owner).permit(:id, :name, :address, dogs_attributes: [:id, :name, :tag])
end
```

Comment: hey, thanks, good call for how to separate the attributes. But I'm still having a problem where update still affects owner's virtual attributes. Any ideas how to make sure they don't affect the virtual attrs?

Comment: I have edited the update method, do you think that will help?

Comment: na, I'm already doing that. I think this may actually be more of an issue with protecting virtual attributes now that this isn't working. I think I need to update or make a new question. Your answer was right for this tho, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :dogs
```

to your `Owner` model